# Randomly loosing WIFI on 1 computer, but not the other

Tags: macos, windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I have a Mac and a PC (now running Windows 8).

My Mac stays connected to the WiFi very nicely, but my PC likes to disconnect every 5 or so minutes. I'm using a Microsoft USB adapter model MN-510.

Here are some odd things I'm seeing:

I'm connected to my university network, but my WiFi is set to "Off":

[image]

However, when I go to my network settings, it seems to be running:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can drop images straight into superuser.com, then they won't expire at some later point, and people will be able to look back at your question.

Comment: The poster needs at least 10 reputation to post images (see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5508/how-do-i-post-an-image-if-i-dont-have-enough-reputation-points-to-do-so and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5599/how-can-i-post-screenshots-with-less-than-10-reputation). I've edited the question to add the images inline, after peer reviewing it will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Microsoft USB adapter MN-510 is not compatible with Windows 8:

[image]

(Screenshot taken from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win8&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=MN-510&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14). The Windows Compatibility Center URL is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home)

(The NIC is [not compatible with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win7/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win7&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=mn-510&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14) either.)

Comment: Oh wow, I never would have thought that...Thanks! 

It just seems like there would be a kind of solution /work around since it seems to work at least some of the time...And I didn't have a problem with it for Win7. OH WELL.

Comment: It's great that your USB NIC was working reliably with Windows 7, but it was living on borrowed time... Looks like Windows 8 changed something that definitely broke compatibility. If you feel that your question is answered, it is customary to mark it as such by selecting an accepted answer. This will make clear that the question is closed and help others with a similar issue. Thanks!